# SSH key errors when connecting a bitbucket git repository to a bamboo plan

Tags: git, ssh, key, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server

I am trying to connect a bitbucket repository to a bamboo plan. The repository host is set to git, and the authentication method is SSH private key. The public key is uploaded to the bitbucket repository and the private is uploaded to bamboo. However, when I try to create the plan using this, I get an error that

```
SSH key file uploaded doesnt contain any key (no -----BEGIN present)
```

However, both the public key and private keys definitely have the -----BEGIN present
so I am unsure of the issue/how to resolve it

The private key has the encryption, public lines, etc. Then starts the private key with:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PRIVATE KEY ----
```

and ends with

```
---- END SSH2 PRIVATE KEY ----
```

If you have had a similar issue or know how to resolve this I would love any insight into the issue.

Comment: You have different ammount of dashes  (4 in comparison to 5).

Comment: Oh wow okay that makes so much sense, my mistake. I ended up resolving it by using a method of connection that did not involve ssh keys, but it's great to know why it didn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving it by using a method of connection that did not involve ssh keys, but as user @Jakuje pointed out, I had an incorrect number of dashes in the private key file, which resulted in the key being unable to read.